# Bubble sort using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bubble-sort

I have recently started learning Python and wanted to try bubble sort. I'm getting the desired output, but is there a way to not have the space after the final element?

> My Output
> (0 1 2 4 4 5 7 9 14 18 18 )
>
> The output I want
> (0 1 2 4 4 5 7 9 14 18 18)

Ignore the brackets, they are to show the space

```
def bubble(arr):
    n=len(arr)
    for i in range(n-1):
        for j in range(0,n-i-1):
            if arr[j]>arr[j+1]:
                arr[j], arr[j+1]= arr[j+1], arr[j]
    for k in range(n):
        print(arr[k],end=" ")
```

Comment: Whole sorting part is irrelevant since your question is purely about printing the list.

Comment: You can just do `print(arr)`. If you don't like the format, then `print(tuple(arr))`.

Comment: My Output and The output I want are exactly the same. You mean just the last space between 18 and )?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki no they're not, `My Output` has a space at the end. Problem is, this question is about printing the output, not about sorting.

Comment: "is there a way to not have the space after the final element?" Yup, don't print it. You are currently printing a space after every element with `end=" "`. You will need to do something that treats the last element differently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform each integer into a string using `str()`, then use `" ".join` to avoid having to print the trailing space.

```py
print(" ".join(str(item) for item in arr))
```